# How to find out the IsSchemaBound property of a view of another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find out whether a specific view is created by using `SCHEMABINDING` or not in another database (In a `JOIN` statement). Currently I'm using `OBJECTPROPERTY(SV.object_id, 'IsSchemaBound')`. SV.object_id gets the correct object id of the view of another database. But the problem is, the built in function `OBJECTPROPERTY()` is only executable in current database context as per [this ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

Is there a way to execute `OBJECTPROPERTY()` function in another database context?
Or is there any way to get the `IsSchemaBound` property of another database.

Comment: Put it in a SP in the target database and call the SP?

Comment: @DaleK, that's not an option for me right now. I need to call the sp from another database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just select straight out of the relevant database's system views

```sql
select v.*,
  m.is_schema_bound
from YourDB.sys.views v
join YourDB.sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = v.object_id
where v.name = 'SomeView';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use *dynamic sql* in the context of the target database, for example:

```
exec databasename.sys.sp_executesql N'select ObjectProperty(<objectId>, ''IsSchemaBound'')';
```

Comment: I need to execute ObjectProperty function in the JOIN condition. That's where I'm struggling to incorporate sp_executesql. 

For Example:

JOIN ON
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), IV.TABLE_NAME) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SV.NAME)
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(SV.object_id, 'IsSchemaBound') = 1

Comment: @Mazid that would have been useful information and context to put in your question. However you can probably execute the whole statement as a d-sql string, using the above method, just omit the "otherdb" reference and instead use it for the *executesql*

Comment: @Mazid Put the _whole problem_ in the question, including the query (we have no idea what `SV` and `IV` are, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Charlieface for view schemabinding check.

you can create a common table expression and then use the same in your join condition, as you have mentioned in your comments.

```sql
;with cte_schemaboundViews(Name) AS
(select v.name,
  from YourDB.sys.views v
join YourDB.sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = v.object_id
WHERE is_schema_bound = 1
)
SELECT * -- Your columns
FROM YourSchemaName.YourTableName AS IV  -- yourTableName
JOIN cte_schemaboundViews AS SV
ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), IV.TABLE_NAME) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SV.NAME)
```